# Redirecting Hashbang (#!) URLs

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, hashbang

I currently have a `WIX` website. I'm now moving to `Wordpress`. Before I go live with my new site, I need to redirect all the *urls* which includes **hashbangs (#!)** from the old site to the new *pretty urls*.

*Example of old url:*
**mysite.com/#!about/c2tp**

*New url:*
**mysite.com/about**

I've tried to do a `301 redirect in htaccess`, but that doesn't work. I've done a lot of research, but nothing seems to be working for me. I've heard a few people use sitemap to 301 redirect hashbang url, but I cannot understand how they could do this.

*Google has indexed my webpages including the #!.*

Comment: Shebang is so much cooler :)

Comment: Web server doesn't see part after `#` hence you need to do this in JS

Comment: Although that wouldn't have any benefits to my SEO? Does anyone have any experience in using  ?_escaped_fragment_ I've been reading google's blog and came across it. I'm presuming I would use it like this - Redirect 301 /?_escaped_fragment_=about/c2tp /about